# A limit without l'hospital: $\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{4+x}-{\sqrt{4+2x}}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

So I have a limit I'm supposed to solve with L'Hospital (I think) but it's not satisfying me mathematically:

- $\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{4+x}-{\sqrt{4+2x}}}$

I don't understand exactly how to approach this one. I tried dividing through $x$ everywhere, but it's fruitless. I tried separating the fraction but I think this is the simplest form.

Comment: Try to rationalize the denominator first.

Comment: As stated by others, if you have some limit where the denominator has $\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}$, it is usually a good idea to multiply by $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint.** You may write
$$
\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{4+x}-{\sqrt{4+2x}}}=\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{4+x}-{\sqrt{4+2x}}}\dfrac{\sqrt{4+x}+\sqrt{4+2x}}{\sqrt{4+x}+{\sqrt{4+2x}}}=-\left(\sqrt{4+x}+\sqrt{4+2x}\right)
$$ then it becomes easier to obtain your limit as $x \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Use Taylor's formula at order $1$: $\;\sqrt{4+x}=2\sqrt{1+\dfrac x4}=2+\dfrac x4+o(x)$.

Similarly, $\sqrt{4+2x}=2+\dfrac x2+o(1)$, hence
$$\sqrt{4+x}-\sqrt{4+2x}=-\frac x4+o(1)\sim_0-\frac x4$$
so that 
$$\frac x{\sqrt{4+x}-\sqrt{4+2x}}\sim_0 \frac x{-\dfrac x4}=-4.$$

Comment: Although this is correct, this feels to me like killing an ant with a nuclear weapon.

Comment: This is the only standard way. Do you know what one should do in case of cubic roots, for instance?